# Combobox event is not geting invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click of a button a Combo Box gets displayed and on select of a Combo Box .
The change event is not getting called .

Please let me know where i am making the mistake .

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery17.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $("select").change(function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
   var s = $('<select />');
   var data = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo2': 'baz'
}
for(var val in data) {
   $('<option />', {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
}
s.appendTo('body');
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("select").change(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

The problem is that you don't do this inside your `$(document).ready(function(){` block.

Move it into there, otherwise you are setting an event handler on DOM elements that do not yet exist.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on("change", "select", function(){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

As `<select>` tag is appended dynamically so, you have to delegate event on it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place that in the `doc ready` but after appending those to body and yes that is dynamic so delegate the event to `closest parent element` or `document` itself which is the parent of all.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
           var s = $('<select />');
           var data = {
                 'foo': 'bar',
                 'foo2': 'baz'
            }
           for(var val in data) {
               $('<option />', {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
            }
          s.appendTo('body');
       });

       // you need to place that here.
             $(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
                 alert(this.id);
             });

    });
```